# Pandas - appending dictionary to existing row

Tags: python, pandas

For each row, I am computing values and storing them in a dictionary. I want to be able to take the dictionary and add it to the row where the keys are columns.

For example:

Dataframe

```
A  B  C
1  2  3
```

Dictionary:

```
{
    'D': 4,
    'E': 5
}
```

Result:

```
A  B  C  D  E
1  2  3  4  5
```

There will be more than one row in the dataframe, and for each row I'm computing a dictionary that might not necessarily have the same exact keys.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this to get it to work:

```
appiled_df = df.apply(lambda row: func(row['a']), axis='columns', result_type='expand')
df = pd.concat([df, appiled_df], axis='columns')

def func():
    ...
    return pd.Series(dictionary)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the dict values to appear in each row of the original dataframe, use:

```
d = {
    'D': 4,
    'E': 5
}

df_result = df.join(df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(d), axis=1))
```

**Demo**

**Data Input:**

```
df

    A   B   C
0   1   2   3
1  11  12  13
```

**Output:**

```
df_result = df.join(df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(d), axis=1))


    A   B   C  D  E
0   1   2   3  4  5
1  11  12  13  4  5
```

If you just want the dict to appear in the first row of the original dataframe, use:

```
d = {
    'D': 4,
    'E': 5
}


df_result = df.join(pd.Series(d).to_frame().T)


    A   B   C    D    E
0   1   2   3  4.0  5.0
1  11  12  13  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a `for` cycle in your dictionary and assign the values.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], data=[[1,2,3]])
# You can test with df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], data=[[1,2,3], [8,0,33]]), too.
d = {
   'D': 4,
   'E': 5
}
for k,v in d.items():
  df[k] = v

print(df)
```

Output:

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |